# Usar dois headers diferentes pra duas saidas diferentes na mesma chamada

Tags: php, ajax, json, header

Em determinado ponto, eu preciso gerar arquivos XLS em meu sistema, e uso o seguinte header pras saidas:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $name[$a] . '.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Mas, eu não uso a resposta desse método, eu preciso da resposta de outro método que deve devolver um json, estou tentando:

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Eu defino esse header depois de ter chamado os headers anteriores (`'vnd.ms-excel'`) e usado eles, mas a resposta não pega essa segunda definição, ele sempre me retorna com a codificação para `'vnd.ms-excel'`.

Como usar um header pra gerar um .XLS e um segundo pra retornar um json na mesma chamada?

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi direito... Mas, você quer que uma resposta contenha dois tipos diferentes? Isso é apenas suportado como envio (usando Multipart Types), agora respostas não podem ter mais de um tipo, até onde eu saiba. Se você está retornando um `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');` você está dizendo que o retorno é um `vnd.ms-excel'`. Não há como um navegador lidar com dois tipos de dados numa mesma requisição. Por exemplo, você não pode dizer que uma resposta é uma imagem e um JSON ao mesmo tempo, ou é um ou é outro.

Comment: É assim, eu faço uma requisição, construo um XLS (ou vários) e salvo eles em um diretório, nessa parte eu preciso de do header vnd.ms-excel, mas eu verifico se ele salvou o arquivo e aí sim eu preciso da resposta em json, pra dizer pro client se conseguiu ou não salvar os arquivos